# How does an email client read the content-type headers for encoding?

Tags: email, character-encoding, smtp, imap

It is possible to send an email with different content types: text/html, text/plain, mime, etc. It also is possible to use different encodings, including (according to the RFCs) for header fields: us-ascii, utf8, etc.

How do you solve the chicken and egg problem? The `content-type` header is just one of several headers. If the headers can be any encoding, how does a mail server or client know how to read the `content-type` header if it does not know what encoding the headers themselves are in?

I can see it if the first line, e.g. had to be the `content-type` and it had to be in a pre-agreed encoding, (e.g. ascii), but that is not the case.

How do you parse a stream of bytes whose encoding is embedded as a string inside that very same stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers are defined to be in ascii.  They can be in utf-8 if agreed to out of band, such as via the smtp or imap utf-8 capability extensions.

Internationalization in headers is performed via "encoded words", where the encoding is part of the header data. (This looks like a string such as =?iso8859-1?q?sample_header_data?=).  See rfc2047.

Content Type headers do not apply to headers themselves, only the body content.

Comment: So the assumption is that headers are ascii? If I want to read it off the disk, I read it encoded as ascii, read the headers, and if I discover that the encoding is utf8, then read the body (or reread the whole thing) using utf8?

Comment: Normally, you'd use a mime parser library.  But yes, read as binary, interpret headers in ascii.  If it's multipart, interpret the boundary as an opaque set of bytes to break up the body into sub parts and then recurse  in each part.  If it's a regular part, undo the content transfer encoding, and interpret the bytes in character set indicated by content type header.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely will use a mime parser library. But for my purposes, it was really important to do some basic parsing of the raw data from disk first. Thank you, @Max

Comment: Real life complicates thing: broken mailers sometimes send illegal 8 bit data for header values.  A good heuristic is to check for 8 bit characters, if so, decode as UTF8 and if it's not well formed, interpret as latin1.

Comment: N kidding. Assume it is ascii, but in the meantime check for 8 bit characters, but if not well-formed.... It sounds like there is even less adherence to standards in mailers than in browsers!

Comment: Yes, parsing email is a whole can of worms if you want to work around all of the brokenness found in real-world email clients and servers. For a good read on this, check out the "Why email is hard" series here: http://quetzalcoatal.blogspot.com/search/label/email-hard